# Outlook attachment contains some unknown images "image00001" if I add "Outlook Item" type of attachment or share document via link

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

My goal is to check all attachments from email and show a message with a recommendation to upload file to cloud and share file by link if even one of them located on PC.

Currently, if I add some file from PC, in this case

```cs
item.Attachments.Count = 1;
att.Type = Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
```

and I can check it like this

```cs
public bool IsAttachmentLocal(Outlook item)
{
    foreach (Outlook.Attachment att in item.Attachments)
    { 
        if (att.Type == Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue && null == att.PathName)                  
        return true;
    }
}
```

But if I add some "Outlook Item" (message) or some file via cloud location, then item.Attachments.Cout = 5.
The first element of this array is file with type olEmbeddeditem or 7(in case with cloud location file). 
The next four elements some unknown images with name "image00001" which are have

```cs
att.Type = Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
```

and passed my checking.

I have a suspicion, that it can be thumbnail image.

How can I check the file location in this case? Can I pass these images somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to detect embedded images in Outlook. Here is a sample code for adding such images:

```
Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(@"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg"
    , OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "Some image display name");

string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";   

attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);

newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>", imageCid);
```

So, you can do in the reverse order - get the image CID property value and check whether the message body contains any `img` tags with such mentions.

```
string imageCid = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E");

bool toSkip = newMail.HTMLBody.Contains(imageCid);
```

Answer (score 1):

7 is ATTACH_BY_WEB_REF. The attachment itself must be a *.url file. Its format is something like the following.

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.mysite.demo/myfile.ext
```

Comment: This is interesting because when I drag/drop a file to the outlook calendar I get this type (7). And I can't add it like that directly from VBA itself. Is outlook generating InternetShortcut to local files when drag/dropping them?